# Understanding Self Join with function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, self-join, cumulative-sum

Can anyone help me to understand my query? I know it is correct but somehow I don't know how I come up with this result.

Query:

```
Select 
    A.Name, A.Age, SUM(B.Age) Running_Total
from 
    infoTbl  A, infoTbl B 
Where 
    A.Age <= B.Age 
Group By 
    A.Name, A.Age
Order By 
    A.Age Desc
```

Result:

```
Name    Age   Running Total
---------------------------
A        25        25
B        20        45
C        18        63
D        15        78
E        1         79
F        5         84
```

What is the meaning of

```
Where A.Age <= B.Age
```

Can you give me an illustration? Thank you so much.

Comment: As I see u getting Sum of ages, which are equal or less then current age. in other words sum of current and all previous ages.

Comment: is that per row that is grouped by?

Comment: yes it is if I understand u correctly...

Comment: Yes, I get it Sir but where the comparison starts?

Comment: your original query and the results did not match

Answer (score 1):

Let's break your query into steps

1.

```
Select 
    A.Name, A.Age, b.Name as bName, B.Age as bAge
from 
    infoTbl  A, infoTbl B 
Where 
    A.Age <= B.Age 
Order By 
    A.Age desc, B.Age
```

it is equivalent of

```
Select 
    A.Name, A.Age, b.Name as bName, B.Age as bAge
from 
    infoTbl  A
    inner join infoTbl B on A.Age <= B.Age 
Order By 
    A.Age desc, B.Age
```

That will give you: for each record in table A a record in B with the same age or higher.

```
Name    Age   bName   bAge
---------------------------
A        25    A       25
B        20    B       20
B        20    A       25
C        18    C       18
C        18    B       20
C        18    A       25
...
etc...
```

when you now add sum and group by what you are getting isa total age of say people that are of age equal to a.age or older

```
Select 
    A.Name, A.Age, SUM(B.Age) AS Running_Total
from 
    infoTbl  A
    inner join infoTbl B on A.Age <= B.Age
group by
    A.Name, A.Age 
Order By 
    A.Age desc



Name    Age   Running Total
---------------------------
A        25        25          (25)
B        20        45          (20 + 25 which is age of B+A)
C        18        63          (18 + 20 + 25 which is age of C+B+A)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Where A.Age>=B.Age` get you the next row you want to add.

you can use this instead of self join

```
select *,sum(Age)over(order by Name) as Running_Total from table
```